# How can I put the asp.net "Login" view on the layout page, instead of @Html.Actionlink to a separate login page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

This may be something basic that I am overthinking, but I cannot seem to find a solid solution without getting model binding errors. Basically I want this _layout.cshtml markup:

```
    <div class="row">
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
```

To show the markup of the login form I have, rather than the link to a seperate View. The markup for the _LoginPartial page is what comes with the startup web site template:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-form pull-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.Name + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
}
}
else
{
     @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
}
```

Particularly, I am looking to have the line in the 'else' branch show this markup:

```
@model Accepted.Web.Models.LoginModel

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-form pull-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.Name + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

I tried to just throw the markup I want in the RenderPartial, but since it is strongly typed, the engine complains if I am passing a different model for another view. This obvious won't work since I am going to have lots of strongly typed views floating around, and this login/logout markup needs to be on every page. What design solution would work for the requirements I have? Include the LoginModel.cs in *every* ViewModel I create? Not sure I would like to go that route. Another option I saw was having a BaseViewModel that have the LoginModel in it, which helps keep the DRY principle, but I feel may violate KISS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `RenderAction` and let the controller create a ViewModel:

```
public class CommonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LoginForm()
    {
        var model = new LoginModel();
        return PartialView("_LoginPartial", model);
    }
}
```

Then use `RenderAction` in the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("LoginPartial", "Common"); }
```

This approach has causes some overhead because it has to go through the controller pipeline, but I think it negligible.

Note: I took the liberty to name the controller `Common`, but this can be any name of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me test this out real quick. Just to make sure I understand the semantics here, CommonController is something of a catch-all controller to use for needs like this?

Comment: @davidisawesome yes, as the name says, you can use it for common components on your website. Login forms, (sub)menus, breadcrumbs etc. But I think it's also fine to put a LoginPartial like this in a `UserAccountController` for example.

Comment: Great! That works like a charm. Love the simplicity here, +10 point for you good sir.

Comment: @davidisawesome nice, glad I could help! I usually use this approach when I have re-usable logic in views.